# Creating a massive matrix, selecting specific rows from a file

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a bunch of mat files containing a large sequence of data in the form of rows (7 rows x 160000 samples in each file). I need to create a matrix from certain rows.

I have used the following code to load files:

```
files = dir ('*.mat');
data = load (files(1).name);
for k = 2:numel(files);
  data (k) = load (files(k).name);
end
```

So I have all my data from mat files organised neatly in one structure array. 
Then I was using this kind code to create a matrix:

```
A = [data(1).mydata(7,:); data(2).mydata(7,:); data(3).mydata(7,:); ...
     data(4).mydata(7,:); data(5).mydata(7,:); data(6).mydata(7,:); ...
     data(7).mydata(7,:); data(8).mydata(2,:); data(9).mydata(2,:); ...
     data(10).mydata(2,:)];  %data matrix
```

But then I have a larger number of files, and when I want to create a different matrix I have to change 50 - 70 numbers manually and this piece of code becomes bulky and it's easy to make a mistake.

Is there any other way to do it, like to index that I need the 2nd row from the first 21 fields and the 7th row from the following 21 fields?

Or do I need to load files differently from the very beginning?

Answer (score 0):

If each of your MAT-files has a single variable `mydata` in it, I would load them as follows:

```matlab
files = dir ('*.mat');
data = cell(numel(files),1);
for k = 1:numel(files);
  tmp = load(files(k).name);
  data{k} = tmp.mydata;
end
```

Indexing is now a little bit easier.

You can, for example, use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to extract row 7 from each element in the cell array:

```matlab
A = cellfun(@(d)d(7,:),data,'UniformOutput',false');
A = cat(1,A{:});
```

To extract row 7 from the first 7 elements, and row 2 from the remaining:

```matlab
A1 = cellfun(@(d)d(7,:),data(1:7),'UniformOutput',false');
A2 = cellfun(@(d)d(2,:),data(8:end),'UniformOutput',false');
A = cat(1,A1{:},A2{:});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! So loading data in the form of a cell array rather than structure array makes it easier to apply functions to it.. Thank you!

Comment: @Vitto: There is a `structfun` equivalent for structs, but it iterates over the fields of the struct, not over the array elements. So a struct array is a bit more involved to use in this case, simply because you don't use the fields meaningfully (you have just one field). If your problem involves multiple fields (multiple variables loaded from each file), then the answer might be different.